# Embed documents from event data in MongoDB with aggregation framwork or map/reduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following data structure and would like to embed the documents containing the loc field into the documents containing the duration but only when the timestamp is within the timestamp (ts) minus the duration in seconds of the parent document. 
Is this possible with the aggregation framework or else with map reduce?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53df2a44e6583c76253c9869"),
    "deviceId" : NumberLong(1377700226807),
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:55.000Z"),
    "duration" : NumberLong(1642),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53df2a41e6583c4e243c9869"),
    "deviceId" : NumberLong(1377700226807),
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:53.000Z"),
    "loc" : {
        "lon" : 5.1101453,
        "lat" : 52.0625047
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53df2a3fe6583c38203c986a"),
    "deviceId" : NumberLong(1377700226807),
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:50.000Z"),
        "loc" : {
            "lon" : 5.1101297,
            "lat" : 52.0625031
        }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53df2a44e6583c76253c9869"),
    "deviceId" : NumberLong(1377700226807),
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:55.000Z"),
    "duration" : NumberLong(3600),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53df2a38e6583c03253c9869"),
    "deviceId" : NumberLong(1377700226807),
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:44.000Z"),
        "loc" : {
            "lon" : 5.1101176,
            "lat" : 52.0625171
        }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53df2a33e6583c51243c9869"),
    "deviceId" : NumberLong(1377700226807),
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:38.000Z"),
        "loc" : {
            "lon" : 5.1101409,
            "lat" : 52.0625818
        }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53df2a2de6583c38203c9869"),
    "deviceId" : NumberLong(1377700226807),
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:32.000Z"),
        "loc" : {
            "lon" : 5.1099513,
            "lat" : 52.0624157
        }
}
```

**This is the desired format**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53df2a44e6583c76253c9869"),
    "deviceId" : NumberLong(1377700226807),
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:55.000Z"),
    "duration" : NumberLong(1642),
    "data" : [
       {
          "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:53.000Z"),
          "loc" : {
             "lon" : 5.1101453,
             "lat" : 52.0625047
          }
       },
       {
          "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:50.000Z"),
          "loc" : {
            "lon" : 5.1101297,
            "lat" : 52.0625031
           }
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you give a document exemplifying your desired output? Do you want to change the documents in the collection or create new documents? Are you mixing different types of documents in one collection? How are you using these documents? Prima facie, this seems like a problem best solved with schema design rather than with aggregation or map/reduce.

Comment: I added the example, I prefer to modify current data but creating a new collection is also an option. The collection contains car event data, an event can be an end of ride event which contains a duration and an end-time. It will also contain location events made during a ride. These events are stored in the same collection.

Currenty I am handling this with processing it via a cron, but wonder if I could do it with aggregation. But think it is impossible   since there is nothing to do a group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't easily done with Aggregation framework, but it can be done with MapReduce.

Assuming that the data is property collected (i.e. there are no missing "ride" documents with duration for the documents with "loc" values) you can do it this way:

```
map=function () {
   var startTime;
   if (this.hasOwnProperty("duration"))
       startTime=this.ts-this.duration*1000;
   else
       startTime=this.ts;
   emit(this.deviceId, {startTs:new Date(startTime), endTs:this.ts, loc:this.loc, duration:this.duration});
}
```

Map outputs things in normalized format, reduce groups them all into a single array per deviceId.

```
reduce=function (key,values) {
   var result = { vals : [ ] };
   values.forEach(function(v) {
       result.vals.push(v);
   })
   return result;
}
```

All the actual processing (grouping for each deviceId) happens in `finalize` function which gets an array for each `deviceId`, which it sorts, and groups into the document you are expecting.

```
finalize=function (key, value) {
    var lastI=-1;
    var result = {rides: [ ] };
    var ride = { };
    value.vals.sort(function(a,b) { return a.startTs.getTime() - b.startTs.getTime(); } );

    for (i=0; i<value.vals.length; i++) {
        if (value.vals[i].loc == null ) {
           if (ride.hasOwnProperty("locations")) {
               result.rides.push(ride);
               ride={};
           }
           ride["start"]=value.vals[i].startTs;
           ride["end"]=value.vals[i].endTs;
           ride["duration"]=value.vals[i].duration;
           ride["locations"]=[];
           lastI=i;
        } else {
           ride.locations.push({ loc: value.vals[i].loc, ts: value.vals[i].endTs});
        }
    }
    result.rides.push(ride);
    return result;
}
```

I added a couple of deviceIds to your test data:

```
db.rides.find({},{_id:0})
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226807"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:32Z"), "loc" : { "lon" : 5.1099513, "lat" : 52.0624157 } }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226910"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:32Z"), "loc" : { "lon" : 5.1099513, "lat" : 52.0624157 } }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226807"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:38Z"), "loc" : { "lon" : 5.1101409, "lat" : 52.0625818 } }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226910"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:38Z"), "loc" : { "lon" : 5.1101409, "lat" : 52.0625818 } }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226807"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:44Z"), "loc" : { "lon" : 5.1101176, "lat" : 52.0625171 } }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226910"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:44Z"), "loc" : { "lon" : 5.1101176, "lat" : 52.0625171 } }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226807"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:55Z"), "duration" : NumberLong(3600) }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226910"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:55Z"), "duration" : NumberLong(3600) }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226807"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:50Z"), "loc" : { "lon" : 5.1101297, "lat" : 52.0625031 } }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226908"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:50Z"), "loc" : { "lon" : 5.1101297, "lat" : 52.0625031 } }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226807"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:53Z"), "loc" : { "lon" : 5.1101453, "lat" : 52.0625047 } }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226908"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:53Z"), "loc" : { "lon" : 5.1101453, "lat" : 52.0625047 } }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226807"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:55Z"), "duration" : NumberLong(1642) }
{ "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226908"), "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:55Z"), "duration" : NumberLong(1642) }
```

and ran it through MR

```
db.rides.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out:"newrides", finalize:finalize})
{
        "result" : "frides",
        "timeMillis" : 47,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 14,
                "emit" : 14,
                "reduce" : 3,
                "output" : 3
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

results are:

```
db.newrides.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : NumberLong("1377700226807"),
        "value" : {
                "rides" : [
                        {
                                "start" : ISODate("2014-08-04T05:37:55Z"),
                                "end" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:55Z"),
                                "duration" : NumberLong(3600),
                                "locations" : [
                                        {
                                                "loc" : {
                                                        "lon" : 5.1099513,
                                                        "lat" : 52.0624157
                                                },
                                                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:32Z")
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "loc" : {
                                                        "lon" : 5.1101409,
                                                        "lat" : 52.0625818
                                                },
                                                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:38Z")
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "loc" : {
                                                        "lon" : 5.1101176,
                                                        "lat" : 52.0625171
                                                },
                                                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:44Z")
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        {
                                "start" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:10:33Z"),
                                "end" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:55Z"),
                                "duration" : NumberLong(1642),
                                "locations" : [
                                        {
                                                "loc" : {
                                                        "lon" : 5.1101297,
                                                        "lat" : 52.0625031
                                                },
                                                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:50Z")
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "loc" : {
                                                        "lon" : 5.1101453,
                                                        "lat" : 52.0625047
                                                },
                                                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:53Z")
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : NumberLong("1377700226908"),
        "value" : {
                "rides" : [
                        {
                                "start" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:10:33Z"),
                                "end" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:55Z"),
                                "duration" : NumberLong(1642),
                                "locations" : [
                                        {
                                                "loc" : {
                                                        "lon" : 5.1101297,
                                                        "lat" : 52.0625031
                                                },
                                                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:50Z")
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "loc" : {
                                                        "lon" : 5.1101453,
                                                        "lat" : 52.0625047
                                                },
                                                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:53Z")
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                ]
        }
}
{
        "_id" : NumberLong("1377700226910"),
        "value" : {
                "rides" : [
                        {
                                "start" : ISODate("2014-08-04T05:37:55Z"),
                                "end" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:55Z"),
                                "duration" : NumberLong(3600),
                                "locations" : [
                                        {
                                                "loc" : {
                                                        "lon" : 5.1099513,
                                                        "lat" : 52.0624157
                                                },
                                                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:32Z")
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "loc" : {
                                                        "lon" : 5.1101409,
                                                        "lat" : 52.0625818
                                                },
                                                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:38Z")
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "loc" : {
                                                        "lon" : 5.1101176,
                                                        "lat" : 52.0625171
                                                },
                                                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:44Z")
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your and Neil's answers give me a much better understanding on how to use map reduce, I already tried it myself but didn't come this far. 
My data set might have missing ride events (they will come in later) so there will be documents containing the loc without a corresponding ride. I think I will be capable of solving this myself based on your answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation framework has no way of "retaining" information across documents when processing the pipeline. The sort of "parent/child" relationship you are describing where that element is decided by comparison to a "parent" document which is not otherwise specified directly in the documents is therefore not possible here.

The mapReduce method however has access to "global" scoped variables. This can allow "idenification" of parent details which can then be stored in a variable for comparison to possible children as you require.

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function() {
    lastValue.data = [];

    if ( lastId == null || this.hasOwnProperty("duration") ) {
      lastId = this._id;
      lastValue.deviceId = this.deviceId;
      lastValue.ts = this.ts;
      lastValue.duration = this.duration;
    }

    if (
        ( this.hasOwnProperty("loc") ) &&
        (
          ( lastValue.ts.valueOf() - ( lastValue.duration * 1000 ) ) <
          this.ts.valueOf()
        )
      )
      lastValue.data.push({
        "ts": this.ts,
        "loc": this.loc
      });


    emit ( lastId, lastValue );

  },
  function (key,values) {

    var reduced = {};

    values.forEach(function(value) {
      if ( !reduced.hasOwnProperty("deviceId") ) {
        reduced.deviceId = value.deviceId;
        reduced.ts = value.ts;
        reduced.duration = value.duration;
        reduced.data = [];
      }

      value.data.forEach(function(dat) {
        reduced.data.push(dat);
      });

    });

    return reduced;

  },
  { 
      "sort": { "ts": -1 },
      "scope": { "lastId": null, "lastValue": {} }, 
      "out": { "inline": 1 }
  }
)
```

So essentially this is "storing" the "key" to be emitted as "lastId" with the use of the "scope" declarations available to mapReduce. Clear the "parent" documents contain a duration so there is something to use here.

The "data" element needs to be emitted as an array. This is due to a [requirement of the "reduce" function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function) as described in the documentation. The key thing being that the input must be in the same format as the expected input. The "reduce" function can be called more than once per "key".

The condition in the "mapper" can restrict the values that are present in this array before the "reduce" function is called though. This also avoids relying on adding a "finalize" method in case there is only a single "key" emitted, and the "reduce" function would not then touch this item. So less work to do the filtering up front.

The "reducer" then is now relegated to just "merging" the results to combine the elements in "data" that qualified for inclusion as "children".

Naturally the sort order is by the "descending" timestamp or "ts" values. This would be a good point to index, and the order aligns with how the documents are processed for comparison so each "breakpoint" is valid where a new parent is detected.

The output is of course in the mapReduce style. So getting to your "exact" desired output would require a little more post processing, but as you see it is basically the result:

```js
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53f15b8beb75bdce84f914a1"),
            "value" : {
                "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226807"),
                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:55Z"),
                "duration" : NumberLong(1642),
                "data" : [
                    {
                        "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:53Z"),
                        "loc" : {
                            "lon" : 5.1101453,
                            "lat" : 52.0625047
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T08:37:50Z"),
                        "loc" : {
                            "lon" : 5.1101297,
                            "lat" : 52.0625031
                        }
                    }
                ]
             }
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53f15b8beb75bdce84f914a4"),
            "value" : {
                "deviceId" : NumberLong("1377700226807"),
                "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:55Z"),
                "duration" : NumberLong(3600),
                "data" : [
                    {
                        "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:44Z"),
                        "loc" : {
                            "lon" : 5.1101176,
                            "lat" : 52.0625171
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:38Z"),
                        "loc" : {
                            "lon" : 5.1101409,
                            "lat" : 52.0625818

                    },
                    {
                        "ts" : ISODate("2014-08-04T06:37:32Z"),
                        "loc" : {
                            "lon" : 5.1099513,
                            "lat" : 52.0624157
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

Note that the output given here as different `_id` values than the sample since the sample contains "duplicate" values for `_id`, which of course is not allowed on the primary key.